# How can i make a shared function for form load in a seperate class file n vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, function

i would like to have a shared function in a separate class file to address the form location .
but i dont know how can i get this to work.
if i use this below code in my form its working . but i cannot move this to a class file.

```
     Shared Sub Formlocation()
         Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
         Me.Location = Screen.GetWorkingArea(Me).Location
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the Form-Instance "Me" from outside the class instance.

Change the function to a parametrized Sub and pass the Form Instance at the call to the Sub

```
Shared Sub Formlocation(ByVal frm As Form)
    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    frm.Location = Screen.GetWorkingArea(frm).Location
End Sub
```

An alternative could be an Extension-Method (.NET 3.5 and up)

Comment: As an FYI, `frm` should not be passed `byref` unless you plan on creating a new instance of it in the method.

Comment: well. as it is an object it will anyway pass a reference, or not?

Comment: Yes, objects are passed by reference, but what you are doing is passing a reference to the original variable, which is generally not a good practice. The issue is that if the called method modifies the value of the variable itself (i.e. `frm = new Form`), this will propagate back to the caller with byref. If the parameter was not byref, the assignment would be strictly local to the method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you may want to have functionality that is common to some of your forms.

If this is the case, you might want to consider creating a base class that inherits from `Form`, have each of your applicable forms inherit from this, and then call the method from the form.

For example, here is a sample of the base form:

```
Public Class MyBaseForm
    Inherits Form

    ' Contains standard sizing logic, but can be overridden by inheritors
    Protected Overridable Sub InitializeFormLocation()
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Me.Location = Screen.GetWorkingArea(Me).Location
    End Sub

    ' An optional method for initializing the form location that will be automatically implemented for all child forms
    Private Sub MyBaseForm_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call InitializeFormLocation()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is an example of a child form

```
Public Class MyForm1
    Inherits MyBaseForm

    ' An optional way for the child forms to call the method
    Private Sub DoInitialization()
        Call MyBase.InitializeFormLocation()
    End Sub
End Class
```